Fabrication of Planar HASEL soft actuators
Recently, I was researching planar HASEL actuators to create artificial muscles. I was greatly inspired by the YouTube video "HASEL actuators with muscle-like performance."
I found the paper "Hydraulically amplified self-healing electrostatic actuators with muscle-like performance" by Acome et al.1, where they described two types of planar HASEL actuators, a donut-shaped one and an in-plane "stretchy" version. I would like to make the in-plane version.
Here is an image of the actuator I'm interested in:
.
In the paper, they give two materials that are used to produce general planar HASELs: Ecoflex 00-30 and polydimethylsiloxane. For the in-plane version, Ecoflex 00-30 was the most promising, but I realized that the silicone substance was more opaque than the actuator's shell. What material is used to make the elastometric shell of the HASEL actuator? How is the whole thing assembled?

1 E. Acome, S. K. Mitchell, T. G. Morrissey, M. B. Emmett, C. Benjamin, M. King, M. Radakovitz, C. Keplinger: Hydraulically amplified self-healingelectrostatic actuators with muscle-like performance, Science, doi 10.1126/science.aao6139
